# Algebraic manipulation of Lyapunov function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, systems-of-equations

I have a problem I would like some feedback on. I have spent 6 hours on it examining various techniques (numerically and analytically).

I need to find the values of $k$ for which $x^2+ky^2$ is a Liapunov function for the system $$\dot{x}=-x+y-x^2-y^2+xy^2, \dot{y}=-y+xy-y^2-x^2y$$

**My attempt:** $$\dot{V} = \frac{\partial V}{\partial x} \times \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial y} \times \frac{dy}{dt} = 2x(-x+y-x^2-y^2+xy^2)+2ky(-y+xy-y^2-x^2y)=-2x^2+2xy-2x^3-2xy^2+2x^2y^2-2ky^2+2kxy^2-2ky^3-2kx^2y^2 \leq 0$$

**Note:** Global stability is NEVER established because of the counterexample $(x,y)=(-2,0)$. Then, $$\dot{V}=2x(-x+y-x^2-y^2+xy^2)+2ky(-y+xy-y^2-x^2y)=2(-2)(2+0-4-0+0)+0=8 \nleq 0.$$ So we are concerned with establishing local stability only. It turns out that if $k=1$, then $$\dot{V}=-2x^2+2xy-2x^3-2xy^2+2x^2y^2-2y^2+2xy^2-2y^3-2x^2y^2=-2x^2-2y^2-2x^3-2y^3+2xy \leq 0 \implies x^2+y^2+x^3+y^3-xy \geq 0 \implies (x^2+y^2-xy)(x+y+1) \geq 0.$$
Upon solving the inequality, we see that for REAL $x,y$, the solution is $y\ \geq -x-1$. It turns out the domain of stability of the origin for $k=1$ is the set $x^2+y^2=\frac{1}{2}$.

**Method 1:** Following Evgeny's suggestion below, I tried $$x=r\cos\theta, y=\frac{r}{k}\sin\theta.$$ Then assuming my calculations are correct (I verified them several times) I end up with the following equation after multiplying all terms by $k^2$:
$$r^2\cos^2\theta-kr^2\sin\theta\cos\theta+k^2r^3\cos^3\theta+r^3\cos\theta-r^3\cos^3\theta-r^4\cos^2\theta+r^4\cos^4\theta+kr^2-kr^2\cos^2\theta-kr^3\cos\theta+kr^3\cos^3\theta+r^3\sin^3\theta+kr^4\cos^2\theta-kr^4\cos^4\theta \geq 0.$$

Upon attempting to bound terms, I ran into great difficulty (I won't elaborate here but it suffices to say I didn't get what I needed). This expression is monstrous, with lots of differing terms and exponents! **How can I proceed?**

**Method 2:** Upon Evgeny's other suggestion below, I linearized the system at the origin to get $$\dot{x}=-x+y, \dot{y}=-y,$$ which has eigenvalues $-1,-1$. Then $$\dot{V}=2x(-x+y)+2ky(-y)=-2x^2+2xy-2ky^2=x^2-xy+ky^2 \geq 0 \implies$$

$$(x-\frac{y}{2})^2 = x^2-xy+\frac{y^2}{4} or (x-\sqrt{k}y)^2=x^2-2\sqrt{k}xy+ky^2 \implies k=1/4$$.

I proceeded to verify this using the critical point test for multivariable functions and evaluated the determinant of the Hessian, obtaining $(-2/3,0)$ as a saddle point and $(2.239,-2.517)$ as a saddle point for $k=1/4$. I also graphed the surface on Google Plot.

**Summary:** I have tried different things and obtained $k>0$. My question is: **Which of my methods are valid, and how can they be improved?**

Thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend going to generalized polar coordinates: $x = r \cos \phi$, $y = \frac{r}{k} \sin \phi$. When you do this, you'll get terms that are somewhat easier to bound. This should work, because this is method which is usually taken when proving that structurally stable knots/focuses have Lyapunov function too. Also, are you looking for global Lyapunov function or local?

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that. I'm looking for local.

Comment: If you're looking for local Lyapunov function, you also may do the following. First, find Lyapunov function for linearization of your system in neighbourhood of steady state. If it's structurally stable (i.e., no eigenvalues of linearization at steady state have zero real part), then you may just use the same function for you original nonlinear system but in some smaller neighbourhood.